# Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I am trying to access a MySQL database in the Spring framework but I am getting the following error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
    - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.jta.XADataSourceWrapper; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans


Action:

Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

Here is my code:

pom.xml dependencies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

application.properties

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc.mysql://localhost:3306/geektextdatabase

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=littlegraycells


# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle= true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query= SELECT 1


# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

adminportalapplication.java

```
package com.adminportal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class AdminportalApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminportalApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me, tell me what I am missing? Am I missing any dependencies? I am using Java 9, I don't know if that might be causing trouble.

Comment: where have you defined your datasource bean?

Comment: In which file should I add it?

Comment: There is some problem in in the spring.datasource property definition in application.properties file. Please cehck

Comment: You are excluding the datasource auto configuration and still expect it to auto configure the datasource?!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error, There is a spring config class HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration (it is in your classpath from dependencies) which is    dependent on a datasource bean which is not found

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Thus, in short is your DataSource bean defined? if not define in your configuration file (or inside  AdminportalApplication.java)

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Read [more here how to configure a datasource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html)

Answer (score -2):

You didn't register a bean named `DataSource` which actually represents a bean which connects to your database, you can find a lot of tutorials online how to setup your `DataSource` bean inside of your context in `Spring` and here is [one](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/). I understand it's maybe not one of the best examples, but as I said there is a lot of them online and you can probably find the one that suits you the best

Comment: I am not sure where to include it

Comment: Datasource will be configured automatically when you specify spring.datasource. in application.properties file.(Spring boot Auto Config)